# Solving MINLP with PYOMO and BONMIN

Tags: pyomo

Is it possible to solve a mixed-interger-non-linear-problem (MINLP) with the help of PYOMO and the BONMIN solver?

Comment: Why didn't you simply try it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. BONMIN can solve *convex* MINLP problems and Pyomo can interface with BONMIN through the ASL.

Compile BONMIN / CoinBinary with ASL support (before running `configure`, be sure to go into `ThirdParty/ASL` and run `get.ASL`) and then make sure hat the resulting `bonmin` executable is available through your PATH. Pyomo can then use it by either specifying `--solver=bonmin`  At the `pyomo` command line or with `SolverFactory('bonmin')` within a script.

Do remember that BONMIN is a local solver and that if you hand it a nonconvex problem there are no guarantees as to what you will get out.

Comment: I didn't know about ASL, but actually this is cool stuff: https://software.sandia.gov/downloads/pub/pyomo/PyomoInstallGuide.html#_asl_solvers. I will accept the answer as soon as I have reproduced it successfully. Thanks!